# check API key quota usage using python

Tags: python, api-key

I've been using Python to access data on VirusTotal with my public api keys.

I wondered if it's possible to see the quota usage using Python. I know I can see the data by logging into my VirusTotal account, but if I can see the usage when running my script that would be easier to keep track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably the [user-api-usage](https://developers.virustotal.com/reference#user-api-usage) endpoint.

According to the linked api-docs, the `JSON` object returned is of the format:

```
{
  "data": {
    "daily": {
      "2020-08-10": {
        "urls": 2
      },
      "2020-08-11": {
        "domains": 1,
        "file_relationships": 1,
        "files": 1
      },
      "2020-08-12": {
        "analyses": 25,
        "file_analyse": 3,
        "files": 6
      },
      "2020-08-17": {
        "urls": 3
      },
      "2020-08-18": {
        "urls": 1
      },
      "2020-08-20": {
        "file_download": 36,
        "file_relationships": 5,
        "files": 1
      },
      "2020-08-21": {
        "file_analyse": 1,
        "file_download": 92,
        "files": 1
      },
      "2020-08-23": {
        "analyses": 5,
        "file_analyse": 1
      },
      "2020-08-25": {
        "file_download": 51
      },
      "2020-08-26": {
        "file_download": 51
      },
      "2020-08-28": {
        "file_download": 14
      },
      "2020-08-31": {
        "file_download": 6
      },
      "2020-09-01": {
        "file_download": 81
      },
      "2020-09-02": {
        "file_relationships": 5,
        "graphs": 1
      },
      "2020-09-03": {
        "file_relationships": 6,
        "graph_comments": 1,
        "graph_items": 3,
        "graphs": 2,
        "retrohunt_jobs": 2
      },
      {
     
...

      }
    },
    "total": {
      "analyses": 30,
      "comment_relationships": 1,
      "comments": 4,
      "domain_comments": 1,
      "domain_graphs": 2,
      "domain_relationships": 2,
      "domains": 1,
      "file_analyse": 6,
      "file_behaviours": 6,
      "file_download": 331,
      "file_relationships": 19,
      "files": 9,
      "graph_comments": 2,
      "graph_items": 3,
      "graphs": 8,
      "intelligence_search": 5,
      "resolutions": 1,
      "retrohunt_jobs": 2,
      "search": 6,
      "statistics": 1,
      "submissions": 1,
      "url_relationships": 1,
      "urls": 8
    }
  }
}
```

Which gives you both a by-date breakdown and a "totals" node at the bottom of the stream/file.

The command that the documentation recommends is as follows:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/users/{id}/api_usage \
  --header 'x-apikey: <your API key>'
```

Again, the source for this info is linked above.

EDIT:

A python function commonly used to run shell commands like `curl` is the `system.os()` function. There are other (and possibly even better) solutions for this, but that is out of scope for this answer. To use it in your script, you would add:

```
/usr/bin/env python

import system

...

system.os('curl --request GET  --url https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/users/{id}/api_usage --header \'x-apikey: <your API key>\'')
```

...to your script (Notice the added backslashes escaping the inner quotes.)